# I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@2a01ca1

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

when I try to sign in my app, it does nor working. And when ı Click sign in, my logcat shows me

> I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@4aff803

I checked my build gradle app and project, but ı did not find.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ibrahimkiceci.simplynoteapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

}
```

Also my gradle projects;

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my sign in and sign up activity is ;

```
package com.ibrahimkiceci.simplynoteapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth : FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        // Kullanıcı sürekli email ve password girmemesi için aşağıdaki kodu aktifleştir.

        /*

        val currentUser  = auth.currentUser

        if (currentUser != null) {
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ListViewActivity:: class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

         */
    }


    fun signIn (view: View) {

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mailText.text.toString(), passwordText.text.toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->

                if (task.isSuccessful) {

                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        "Welcome : ${auth.currentUser?.email.toString()}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ListViewActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }


            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    exception.localizedMessage.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()


            }


    }

    fun signUp (view: View) {

        val email = mailText.text.toString()
        val password = passwordText.text.toString()

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener {task ->

            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Your Account Has Been Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ListViewActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }

        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->

            if (exception != null ) {

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Do you know how can ı fix this problem ?, ı have struggled  a few hours but did not find.

Comment: That's not an error message.  It's an informational message.  You can tell because of the letter "I" in front of the log.  If you have some code that is not working, you should edit the question to explain more clearly what is not working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I have solved by add below dependencies

1. Go to your App.build.Gradle file
2. Add below dependencies and test in real device (not in emulator)

   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'
   // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.2.0'

   // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:7.2.0'

   // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:7.2.0'

   // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:7.2.0'

Comment: When you're composing a question or an answer on stackoverflow you need format code, filenames, variables, etc, so I'll be easier to read. Check out this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting